# upload image not moving

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

i have this code :

$this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->credit_rules);

```
    $this->load->model('profile_m');
    $this->load->model('order_m');


        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/user/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config['max_width']  = '2650';
        $config['max_height']  = '2270';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('ktp')  )
        {
            $this->data->error = $this->upload->display_errors();

//          $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_ktp' => $this->upload->data());
//          $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
```

no warning / error appear, submit success but the image which i upload not show up on the folder './uploads/user/' i wonder why, i don't know how to check my upload_path is right or not. i wish for some direction. but i do upload from the different function with a same code it's working and the image show up.

i currently use localhost.

this is the form :

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('pesan')): ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('pesan'); ?>
<?php else:?>
<?php if(@$error){echo @$error;} ?>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php 
echo form_open_multipart(site_url(uri_string()));
echo form_label('KTP');
echo form_upload('ktp');
echo form_submit('submit','Pesan Sekarang');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if your code work and you're not sure about your path you could always check it like this :

```
$upload_path = "./uploads/user/";

if(!file_exists($upload_path)) {
    mkdir($upload_path);
}
```

Because i tried your code and it worked for me too with a valid path, and when i tested with an invalid path you should get an error with : **The upload path does not appear to be valid.** as the error message

Edit 1

Here how i tested it :

The view :

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart(site_url().'/upload_test/uploadImg');?>
        <input type="file" name="ktp" title="Upload ktp" class="btn btn-lg btn-info m-b-sm col-sm-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Go Upload son !">


        <?php echo isset($the_file) ? 'Uploaded file : '.$the_file['file_name'] : ''; ?>
        <?php echo isset($error) ? $error : ''; ?>  
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The controller :

```
public function uploadImg() {

    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/user';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']      = '2048';
    $config['max_width']     = '2650';
    $config['max_height']    = '2270';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
    $config['encrypt_name']  = FALSE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if( ! file_exists($config['upload_path']) ) {
         mkdir($config['upload_path']);
    }


    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('ktp')  ) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }
    else {
        $data['the_file'] = $this->upload->data();

        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }
}
```

Edit 2

My last idea is to do it without codeIgniter helper. Check this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). W3school guide for PHP File Upload.

Comment: already check it sir, but no error appear and that means my path was right, but still the image not show in the directory. hmm.. i wonder why.

Comment: @rudzstyle can you show us your HTML ? It would be lovely.

Comment: it's still prototype so only at localhost. how about i email you the file along with the database sir?

Comment: @rudzstyle would be simpler if you edit your post and add your HTML or just a quick draft of the form that send the upload, but if you want check my profile for my email and i can take a look .

Comment: i didn't find you email address sir, so i edit it and put my view up there. please help me sir.

Comment: I'm really not sure about your    **form_open_multipart(site_url(uri_string()));** i think you should give it a try like my example **site_url()./controller/function**

Comment: already change it to this echo form_open_multipart(site_url().'/store/credit'); but still not working
store = controller
credit = function

Comment: You really have nothing in $this->upload->display_errors(); ? there is something wrong...

Comment: yeah nothing sir.. sorry sir for make you waiting.. yeah i think i will do it with the old way and old way always effective... :) thanks sir, have a good day. really appreciate for your time

Answer (score 0):

You defined some constraints such as max_size, max_width, max_height. Did you check the upload images satisfy all your defined constraints?

Comment: yeah, already check it and it's not the issue here sir. because i using the same code and this 1 not working but the other working with the same image file uploading. but still really appreciate for your time sir. thank you